# One line function or syntax to take input in a list in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, function

Here to take input from user and store it into a list i need to write 5 line of code is there any other alternative for this in python 2.7

```
c = []
for i in range(1,6):
    user = input('enter number: ')
    c.append(user)

print c
```

giving the output as

```
enter number: 1
enter number: 2
enter number: 3
enter number: 4
enter number: 4
>>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be one-liner? It is already readable enough, making it in one line will make things complex

Comment: @AzatIbrakov because this code is unnecessarily raise the length of my function.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
c=[int(input("enter number: "))for i in range(5)]
enter number: 1
enter number: 2
enter number: 3
enter number: 4
enter number: 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: IMO list comprehensions with side effects looks really ugly

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Are you talking about IO in a list comprehension?